# Prestaging user accounts

Tags: active-directory

In Active Directory, what is the concept of prestaging user accounts?

Thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate?  Do you mean pre-staging *computer* accounts?

Comment: If you do mean pre-staging client computers check out this Technet article - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759196(WS.10).aspx

Comment: also look up DJOIN if your prestaging win7 or w2k8r2 computer accounts.

Answer (score 3):

Usually we pre-stage COMPUTER accounts, which simply means creating them in AD before they are joined from the workstation, either manually or using an automated/unattended install script.

For users, this makes no sense as obviously a user must be created in AD before it can log in.